# Deserialize not being called correctly, but can't find method or where called

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

So I have this model:

```
class CdrSheet(models.Model):
    MONTH_CHOICES = ((1, "January"), (2, "February"), (3, "March"), (4, "April"), (5, "May"), (6, "June"), (7, "July"),
                     (8, "August"), (9, "September"), (10, "October"), (11, "November"), (12, "December"))

    uploaded = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    report_year = models.IntegerField(default=datetime.datetime.now().year, blank=False, help_text="Requi"
                                                                                                                 "red")
    report_month = models.IntegerField(choices=MONTH_CHOICES, default=1, blank=False, help_text="Required")
    file = models.FileField(max_length=None, blank=False, upload_to=file_name, help_text="CSV files only")
    carrier = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, help_text="Required")
    ani_field = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="ani", blank=True, help_text="Default: 'ani'")
    ani_country_code = models.CharField(max_length=2, default="", blank=True, help_text="If blank, script will assume "
                                                                                        "numbers are internationally "
                                                                                        "formatted")
    dest_field = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="dest", blank=True, help_text="Default: 'dest'")
    dest_country_code = models.CharField(max_length=2, default="", blank=True, help_text="If blank, script will assume "
                                                                                         "numbers are internationally "
                                                                                         "formatted")
    duration_field = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, default="duration", help_text="Default: 'duration'")
    cost_field = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, default="cost", help_text="Default: 'cost'")
    date_field = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, default="date", help_text="Default: 'date'")
    date_format = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, default="%m/%d/%Y", help_text="Please use format "
                                                                                            "specifications shown at "
                                                                                            "http://strftime.org. "
                                                                                            "Default: '%m/%d/%Y'")
    time_field = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, default="time", help_text="Default: 'time'")
    time_format = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, default="%H:%M:%S", help_text="Please use format "
                                                                                            "specifications shown at "
                                                                                            "http://strftime.org. "
                                                                                            "Default: '%H:%M:%S'")

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('uploaded',)
```

And I have this serializer that should work:

```
class CdrSheetSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CdrSheet
        fields = ('pk', 'uploaded', 'title', 'report_year', 'report_month', 'file', 'carrier', 'ani_field',
                  'ani_country_code', 'dest_field', 'dest_country_code', 'duration_field', 'cost_field', 'date_field',
                  'date_format', 'time_field', 'time_format', 'slug')
        read_only_fields = ('pk', 'uploaded', 'slug')
```

But, when I try to create the object in django rest framework, a TypeError is thrown somewhere within the rest_framework, giving me this:

> Got a `TypeError` when calling `CdrSheet.objects.create()`. This may be because you have a writable field on the serializer class that is not a valid argument to `CdrSheet.objects.create()`. You may need to make the field read-only, or override the CdrSheetSerializer.create() method to handle this correctly.
>   Original exception text was: deserialize() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given).

I am super confused as to where this mysterious deserialize method is being both defined and used. I can't find it anywhere. Is it in the django source code? Is it in the rest-framework code, is it a normal python method? I don't get why it's giving me this error. Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. I did override the save method of the CdrSheet model, but it's pretty big and I didn't want to turn everyone away because of the amount of code. Thanks again!

Here's the full traceback, by request:

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py" in view
  85.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  456.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  453.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py" in create
  20.         self.perform_create(serializer)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py" in perform_create
  25.         serializer.save()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in save
  169.             self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in create
  798.             raise TypeError(msg)

Exception Type: TypeError at /cdrs/
Exception Value: Got a `TypeError` when calling `CdrSheet.objects.create()`. This may be because you have a writable field on the serializer class that is not a valid argument to `CdrSheet.objects.create()`. You may need to make the field read-only, or override the CdrSheetSerializer.create() method to handle this correctly.
Original exception text was: deserialize() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given).
```

And here's my overidden save method. It's not THAT huge, I just thought it might be annoying. So here it is:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # Override the save function

    columns = {}
    columns['ANI'] = self.ani_field if self.ani_field else 'ani'
    columns['DEST'] = self.dest_field if self.dest_field else 'dest'
    columns['DURATION'] = self.duration_field if self.duration_field else 'duration'
    columns['COST'] = self.cost_field if self.cost_field else 'cost'
    columns['DATE'] = self.date_field if self.date_field else 'date'
    columns['TIME'] = self.time_field if self.time_field else 'time'

    if not self.pk:
        title = self.title
        self.slug = unique_slugify(title if title else "{0} cdr from {1}{2:02d}"
                                        .format(self.file.name, self.report_year,
                                                self.report_month), self._meta.get_field('slug').max_length, CdrSheet)

    super(CdrSheet, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def parse_row(row):
        date_format = self.date_format if self.date_format else '%m/%d/%Y'
        time_format = self.time_format if self.time_format else '%H:%M:%S'

        Cdr.create(report=self.pk,
                   report_datetime="{}{}".format(self.report_year, self.report_month),
                   datetime=datetime.datetime.strptime("{} {}".format(row[columns['DATE']], row[columns['TIME']]),
                                                       "{} {}".format(date_format, time_format)),
                   ani="{}{}".format(self.ani_country_code, row[columns['ANI']]),
                   dest="{}{}".format(self.dest_country_code, row[columns['DEST']]),
                   duration=row[columns['DURATION']],
                   cost=row[columns['COST']])

    filename = self.file.path
    cdr_path = os.path.abspath(filename)

    with open(cdr_path) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            parse_row(row)
```

And here are my methods at the top of the models.py file:

```
@receiver(pre_delete)
def delete_catcher(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if sender == CdrSheet:
        cdrs = Cdr.objects.filter(report=instance.pk)
        for cdr in cdrs:
            cdr.delete()


def file_name(instance, filename):
    # To get the filename/path for the uploaded csv file
    return '/'.join([str(instance.report_year) + '{0:02d}'.format(instance.report_month), instance.title +
                     os.path.splitext(filename)[1]])


def unique_slugify(string, max_length, obj):
    slug = slugify(string)

    for x in itertools.count(1):
        if not obj.objects.filter(slug=slug).exists():
            break
        slug = "{}-{}".format(slug[:max_length - len(str(x)) - 1], x)
    return slug
```

I think I found the source of the error. Calling `CdrSheet.objects.create(**validate_data)` brought up this traceback:

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py" in view
  85.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  456.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  453.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py" in create
  20.         self.perform_create(serializer)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py" in perform_create
  25.         serializer.save()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in save
  169.             self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
File "/home/supereman16/PerfectPitchTech/projects/processor_api/sheets/serializers.py" in create
  14.         return CdrSheet.objects.create(**validated_data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  127.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in create
  348.         obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
File "/home/supereman16/PerfectPitchTech/projects/processor_api/sheets/models.py" in save
  110.                 parse_row(row)
File "/home/supereman16/PerfectPitchTech/projects/processor_api/sheets/models.py" in parse_row
  102.                        cost=row[columns['COST']])
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cassandra/cqlengine/models.py" in create
  603.         return cls.objects.create(**kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cassandra/cqlengine/query.py" in create
  713.         return self.model(**kwargs).batch(self._batch).ttl(self._ttl).\
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cassandra/cqlengine/models.py" in __init__
  365.                 value = column.to_python(value)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cassandra/cqlengine/columns.py" in to_python
  491.             return datetime.utcfromtimestamp(DateType.deserialize(value)).date()

Exception Type: TypeError at /cdrs/
Exception Value: deserialize() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: How exactly are you attempting this object creation? What does your call look like? Also, what does the full traceback look like?

Comment: I just typed everything in the drf form and clicked the POST button, letting my save function process the uploaded file and all that stuff, but ultimately just using the django and django-rest-framework backend.

Comment: Without more context, such as your overridden save method (could you place it in a github gist?), the full traceback, exactly what you typed into the DRF form, or your view code, this is very difficult to debug. Is there any more you can provide? It does appear that deserialize is likely from Django (line 133 of django/core/serializers/__init__.py) but it's near impossibly to tell how, when or why it's being called from this info

Comment: Sorry to keep jumping around on the info but I just got a look at the traceback. It looks like the origin in your code is actually in an overridden `create()` method on the serializer. `return super(CdrSheetSerializer, self).create(validated_data)` which ends up calling `instance = ModelClass.objects.create(**validated_data)` on line 782 of rest_framework/serializers.py. That's where the error is occurring, so I would recommend verifying that your `validated_data` is being generated correctly and manually try that CdrSheet.objects.create() with that data.

Comment: The only thing that method did was print out validated_data (which looked beautiful) and call the super method. I meant to get rid of that line. But I'll try manually calling `CdrSheet.objects.create()` that sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. It happened to be a problem with my cqlengine model, and what I was trying to add to it. My model looked like this:

```
# ...
report_datetime = columns.Date(required=True, primary_key=True)
datetime = columns.DateTime(required=True)
# ...
```

And these were the arguments for my create call:

```
Cdr.create( # ... First few args
    report_datetime="{}{}".format(self.report_year, self.report_month),
    datetime=datetime.datetime.strptime("{} {}".format(row[columns['DATE']], row[columns['TIME']]),
                                        "{} {}".format(date_format, time_format)),
            # ... Last few args )
```

I was trying to set a date field to a text value, and it complained. Thanks a bunch guys!